# Does Firebase Hosting provides support for DNSSEC?

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-hosting, network-security, dnssec

Is there any support for DNSSEC for apps hosted on Firebase? According to these 2 reports not:

1. https://viewdns.info/dnssec/?domain=firebaseapp.com
2. https://viewdns.info/dnssec/?domain=web.app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNSSEC is a feature of DNS. Firebase Hosting doesn't provide DNS functionality. You need to check with the DNS provider of the domain you are going to use. `web.app` and `firebaseapp.com` may not be setup with DNSSEC but you shouldn't use them for a production app anyways.

Comment: great explanation, thanks. Well, I'm doing some stuff for research purposes, so the app is on `web.app` and `firebaseapp.com`. However, planning to distribute something to production and host on Firebase, thus it's good to know.